# Overlay of Points on Polygons returns NA in R

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

Edit: update question with more specific information based on previous answer

Sorry for the lack of clarity but this is my first post. I have a set of points that I want to overlay onto the counties of the Bay Area in California using the `over` function such that I get a data frame with the points and a new column that shows which neighborhood each point falls into. I've viewed several other related questions but their answers don't seem to work for the data I'm using. I use `complete.cases` to get rid of the rows with `NA`. I then turn the points into a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`. The projection of the points starts as `NA`, and I set them to `"+init=epsg:3857"` (Google Map/Open Street Map default projection). I then transform the points of the projection to the polygon's, which is : `"+proj=lcc +lat_1=37.06666666666667 +lat_2=38.43333333333333 +lat_0=36.5 +lon_0=-120.5 +x_0=2000000 +y_0=500000.0000000001 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"`

I use `result <- !is.na(over(sfpoints, sfpolygon))` to only overlay the points within San Francisco. However, the `result` data frame is just all NA.

A sample set of points is here:

```
id  lat         lon
1   37.97102    -122.300752
2   37.809869   -122.253598
3   37.782851   -122.45351
4   37.808497   -122.263405
5   37.767335   -122.425399
6   37.79215    -122.423548
7   39.78373    -100.445882
8   37.79215    -122.423548
9   39.78373    -100.445882
10  37.870594   -122.265938
11  39.78373    -100.445882
12  37.870594   -122.265938
13  39.78373    -100.445882
14  37.96979    -121.769799
15  NA          -100.445882
```

The shape file for the neighborhoods can be found here: https://data.sfgov.org/Geographic-Locations-and-Boundaries/Neighborhood-Groups-Map/qc6m-r4ih?

What am I doing wrong? I follow the other responses on defining the correct projections, transforming them so the points and polygons match, and applying an overlay, but it's still not working.

Comment: If you get `NA` for your points when you check the projection, it means you didn't set the projection correctly.

Comment: Thanks - I read that as the solution for other questions, but their solution was always to use proj4string(points) <- proj4string(poly), which I did. Even after that I got NA. How do I set projections correctly?